# Comparing two dates using strtotime issue now that year has changed

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

Hi there i have this code

```
if  ((date('m/d/Y' , $row->dates)) <= (date('m/d/Y', strtotime("-3 day"))) )
```

The basic idea is that i pull a date that from my database ($row->dates) and see whether today's date is more than 3 days further along than the date in the database.

This was working perfectly for dates in 2012 up until 2013 hit. It now always hits the else condition for pulled dates containing 2012, and the 2013 dates now work perfectly.

The dates that are stored in the database are in unix timestamp form ie 1351141261.

I can't quite figure out where it is i am going wrong in comparing the two dates. Obviously there is something in the year section screwing things up. Could anyone help?

Comment: why not do this within the db select?

Comment: Why not make the database do the comparison?  **Edit:** Damn, Dagon beat me to it.

Comment: dragon beat me also.........too fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you convert the date to a string?

```
$row->dates <= strtotime('-3 days')
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use MySQL's built in functions to do that

```
SELECT randomdate WHERE randomdate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY);
```

Comment: date add negative is a little confusing. what about date_SUBTRACT, or just: `SELECT randomdate WHERE randomdate >= CURDATE()- INTERVAL 3 DAY;`

Comment: I actually didn't know you could do it that way, i have always just used date_add. thanks for the lesson dragon!

Answer (score 1):

Compare as timestamps not as formatted strings.

The problem is that they're not in order of highest to lowest magnitudes.

For example, if you formatted as `Y-m-d`, the order will actually be correct.

(Technically speaking, PHP compares strings lexicographically.)